# Core Data - Trying to prefetch attributes for all rows is slow

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm displaying some images in a collection view, and using `SDWebImage` to prefetch thumbnails for all of them.

I'm using a batch size of 20 in the `NSFetchRequest`, but when iterating over every object to get the url of the image I need, the batch size performance gain is wasted. Reloading the data takes 0.3s instead of 0.000295s, which results in a obvious delay in the UI.

I've tried setting `[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"propertyName"]]` but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I guess it's not the method I'm looking for.

Any suggestions ?

Edit:

I am using using an `UICollectionView` backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController` (and delegate) data-source. I am making a `NSFetchRequest` with a batch size of 20 and fetching it via the `NS-FRC`. I also need to get the list of urls from ALL the fetched objects, ie:

```
for(NSManagedObjectSubclass *object in frc.fetchedObjects) 
// this is causing the slow-down, because it's faulting all the objects
// not what you'd want if you have many objects!
{
   [urlList addObject:(object.url)]
}

[SDWebImagePrefetcher prefetchUrls:urlList]; 
// this runs in the background and downloads/gets from cache a list of images
```

Comment: Add some code to your question, this isn't enough detail.

Comment: are you actually downloading the images? or are they stored in core data?

Comment: No. The images are not stored in any way in core data. All the image stuff is handled by `SDWebImage`, a library for asynchronously downloading/caching/and loading images from the cache. I'll try to add some detail in the question.

Comment: @LescaiIonel What did you end up doing, facing the same problem, i don't see any good solutions to *prefetching* data backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController` and not just lazy loading the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `NSFetchRequest`'s class reference, `-setPropertiesToFetch:`. "This value is only used if resultType is set to NSDictionaryResultType."

You're correct that iterating over all of the fetched objects kills the benefit of the small batch size. I'm curious, though, why you need to prefetch all of the image URLs at once. If you're doing this to trigger a download, look into doing that in `-awakeFromFetch`: pass the `object.url` off to your `SDWebImagePrefetcher`, which will enqueue the request and start or continue processing. You'll have to subclass `NSManagedObject` to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that resultType property. 

I'm downloading each image once the collection view cell is visible, but I also want to prefetch the images so that when the user scrolls, they are already loaded. 

The problem is that `SDWebImagePrefetcher` cancels the other operation once you pass it a new array, so that's why I need all the urls at once.

Comment: How about writing your own controller class around `SDWebImagePrefetcher`? That class would accept individual image requests, build its own queue, and then use the callback block in `-prefetchURLs:completed:` to start another batch.